# Сокращение сложного слова

Tags: сокращения, сложные-слова

Допустимо ли такое сокращение?

80-граммовый.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, такая **запись** правильна.

Cложное прилагательное, в котором есть числительное, можно записать в словесной форме (прописью) или в **словесно-цифровой форме** (цифрой и присоединяемым дефисом прилагательным).
Большинство таких прилагательных образуется от формы родительного падежа количественных числительных — ***семисот***летний, **двадцатидвух**километровый, **трёхсотсемидесятисеми**литровый.
(При использовании словесно-цифровой формы записи буквенное наращение после числительных, естественно, не требуется.)

Восьмидесятилетний — 80-летний; восьмидесятиметровый — 80-метровый;
восьмидесятирублёвый — 80-рублёвый; восьмидесятиграммовый — 80-граммовый.

*В Приморье родился **80-граммовый** детеныш жемчужного ската* [в океанариуме].
*Китаем испытан **300-граммовый** ракетный двигатель.*

[Слова, начинающиеся числом](https://www.primavista.ru/blog/2017/01/06/narashheniya-chislitelnyih)